# Взаимодействий php и js

Tags: javascript, php

Как можно передать значение сессии на фронт, чтобы у js был доступ к сессии?
У меня есть интернет магазин и сейчас так сделано, что при клике на добавление товара в корзину, он не может добавиться, если пользователь не авторизован, если нету сессии с ним. Это сделано на пхп. Мне сейчас нужно, чтобы при клике на корзинку (есть у каждого товара) в зависимости от того, авторизован ли пользователь, выводилось соответствующее сообщение
К примеру если пользователь авторизован, то при клике на корзинку вывести сообщение в каком нибудь блоке поверх всего "Товар добавлен в корзину", а если не авторизован, то вывести сообщение "Вы не авторизованы, пожалуйста пройдите по такой то ссылке и авторизуйтесь". Раз событие клика, значит это js, но мне для того, чтобы это сделать, нужно иметь представление, авторизован ли этот пользователь и нужно значение с бэка, с пхп. Как его получить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Вы можете использовать cookie для этих целей.**

Ваш сервер может послать cookie клиенту, далее JS может их читать и управлять ими. Кроме того, при помощи AJAX вы можете сообщать серверу дополнительную информацию о действиях пользователя.
https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie

**2) Вы можете общаться с сервером при помощи AJAX**

Так вы можете узнать от сервера всю необходимую информацию (авторизован или нет, первый раз тут или уже приходил, какие товары в корзине уже есть итд.). Алгоритм довольно прост, послали запрос на сервер при помощи JS, сервер (PHP) что то с ним сделал и отдал вам ответ из которого вы достали всё, что вам нужно.
https://learn.javascript.ru/xmlhttprequest